# C# 'Exception Unhandled' error when trying to parse JSON

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to get information from a JSON file and change the text of a label in C#, but I'm running into this 'Exception Unhandled' error:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'The best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(System.ReadOnlyMemory<byte>, System.Text.Json.JsonDocumentOptions)' has some invalid arguments'
```

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace test
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Label unit_used = label3;

            string QUERY_URL = "JSON URL HERE";
                Uri queryUri = new Uri(QUERY_URL);

            using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                dynamic json_data = js.Deserialize(client.DownloadString(queryUri), typeof(object));

                var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(json_data);

                var rootElement = jsonDocument.RootElement;

                var unitElement = rootElement.GetProperty("unit");

                var unit = unitElement.GetString();

                unit_used.Text = unit;
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

JSON URL HERE is, obviously, replaced with the actual URL in the code - I just can't share it publicly.

The line producing the error is:

`var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(json_data);`

Comment: Why are you using `JavaScriptSerializer` and `WebClient`?

Comment: Why are you trying to do `JsonDocument.Parse()` on an *object* that is the result of `js.Deserialize()` (which already parses)? That's attempting to parse it twice, on top of that JsonDocument.Parse expects a string or Stream or Span<char> kind of type. Certainly not an object that is wrapped into a `dynamic`. Speaking of that: get rid of `dynamic`, forget that it exists, it's only confusing and a sure sign that you need to spend time on creating actual classes with properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`.
Instead, use `System.Text.Json.JsonDocument`:

At the top of your file, add the using directive:

```
using System.Text.Json;
```

If you can't use System.Text.Json, you may be [using and old .NET Framework version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8.1). At the solution explorer, right click on your Project -> Properties -> Application. Check there that the Target Framework is **at least** .NET Framework 4.7.2

[image]

Next, replace these two lines of code

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic json_data = js.Deserialize(client.DownloadString(queryUri), typeof(object));
```

by

```
var json_data = client.DownloadString(queryUri);
```